# Syntax error in "all we've done together" page

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, 10m-questions-milestone

If you follow the link: Ten. Million. Questions. Let's celebrate [all we've done together](https://stackoverflow.com/10m), you get to the page that says:

> This is what 51,000 people looks like.

The word "people" here is not used in the singular sense, and furthermore, it is preceded by a numeral, so it must be plural. The verb "looks" should be "look".

Comment: It's not referring to each of the 51,000 people as individuals, it's referring to them as a single group. "This is what 51,000 people look like" would be appropriate if you had a picture of a person whom each individual resembles, which is not the intention here.

Comment: @JeremyBanks Even if plural things look like something as a single group, shouldn't the verb be plural?--"They look like a couple", not "they looks like a couple." Or, "the two look like a couple", not "the two looks like a couple."

Comment: heh. syntax error in copy? i expected to see code

Comment: This discussion is probably better-suited for English.SE; I'm certainly no expert. One of their answers gives me this rule, which seems to support my interpretation: ["When the group is being considered as a whole, it can be treated as a single entity: “the group was ready to go on stage.” But when the individuality of its members is being emphasized, “group” is plural: “the group were in disagreement about where to go for dinner.”"](http://public.wsu.edu/~brians/errors/group.html)

Comment: At first I agreed with sawa, but the more I think about it, `looks` definitely seems to be correct. If it were `look`, it would imply that we were about to be shown 51,000 individual photos of people.

Comment: @Rob It is ambiguous. It can be taken as either.

Comment: @sawa - *not "they looks like a couple."* - Correct, but you would say "this is what a couple `looks` like", not "this is what a couple `look` like"

Comment: @Rob In that case, "(a) couple" is a singular noun. You would still say "this is what the two look like", not "this is what the two looks like". The verb agrees with the subject. The object is irrelevant.

Comment: Right - and in this case is a singular set of 51,000 people. I disagree it's ambiguous. Colloquially, maybe, but in terms of strict rules, no. The meaning is 'This is how the entire group looks', not 'here are 51,000 photos of people'.

Comment: Given that there's this much argument about which is right, I don't think it's worth [getting someone killed over](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ngOTH.png)

Comment: @KevinB They'd be right if they were talking about each person as an individual in the couple :)

Comment: "Ten. Million. Questions." aren't sentences either.  Shall we talk about that for a moment ;)

Comment: @RichardScriven What is wrong with listing words? They are not ungrammatical. I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Am I the only one here who is really confused and just doesn't care?

Comment: Did you really just ask a question all because it says `looks` instead of `look`? People on this site can be so petty sometimes...

Comment: You should be very afraid of [Jeff Atwood's giant S](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/63791#63791).

Answer (score 11):

The subject of the verb (`looks`) is not always the noun closest to it (`people`). I'm not an English expert, but I believe the subject of this sentence is the word `this`. In other words, replacing the middle part (is that a clause?) with `is what that` it becomes:

`This is what that looks like`.

Correct as it's written, I believe. Perhaps a good question for [english.stackexchange.com](https://english.stackexchange.com/)!

---

I went ahead and asked this question on [english.stackexchange.com](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/268188/is-there-a-sentence-structure-that-allows-for-things-like-people-looks). My reasoning was incorrect, but not my intention!  From the answer there:

> You can't swap "51,000 people" (a plural) for "that" (a singular).
>
> If you swapped it for a simpler pronoun instead, it stops working:
>
> "This is what **they** looks [sic] like."
>
> But it works because of the reasons in chasly's comment. You are referring to the entire crowd of 51,000 as a single entity. "This is what **a crowd of 51,000 people** looks like."
>
> You could say "Here is what 51,000 people **look** like", but the emphasis is on what all the people look like individually, as opposed to what the crowd looks like.

That final sentence is a great point about the intention (I assume) on the 10m page: the idea is to talk about what the crowd looks like ("big") not what the people look like.

Comment: No it is not. "This" is connected to "what", which is underlyingly the object: "51,000 people looks like (what)", and here, "looks" is wrong.

Comment: "51,000 people" is not the same as "a crowd/group of 51,000 people", just like "two apples" is not the same as "a bag of two apples".

Comment: It's phrased this way because 51,000 people is considered an "it".  What is "it"? "It" is 51,000 people.  This is what "it" **looks** like.  51,000 people are considered to be a collective unit here.  It is perfectly correct in the context of the sentence.